# Mis apuntadores a estructura no salen de la funcion y se pierden en la memoria

Tags: c, estructuras-de-datos, dev-c++

Cuando se termina de ejecutar la funcion "crearFila" ninguno de los apuntadores que meti apuntan a una estructura. Si intento imprimir los datos a los que apuntan, el programa entra en un bucle y crashea.

No me habia dado cuenta de esta hasta que intente conectar una nueva fila a la que ya tenia creada anteriormente.

¿Como le hago para que los apuntadores que meta a la funcion logren salir conectados?

```
struct nodo *crearFila (struct nodo *ptrIni, struct nodo *ptrFin, int nmb)
{
    int rc = 1;
    struct nodo *ptrRec1, *ptrRec2;
    ptrIni = crearNodo (nmb);           //Se crea el nodo inicial.
    ptrRec1=ptrIni;
    printf("%d ", ptrRec1->num);
    for (rc;rc<=3;rc++)                 //Se crean los tres nodos intermedios.
    {
        ptrRec2 = crearNodo (nmb);
        ptrRec2->ptrAnt = ptrRec1;
        ptrRec1->ptrSig = ptrRec2;
        ptrRec1 = ptrRec1->ptrSig;
        printf("%d ", ptrRec1->num);
    }
    ptrRec1=ptrIni;
    ptrFin = crearNodo (nmb);           //Se crea el nodo final.
    ptrFin->ptrAnt = ptrRec2;
    ptrRec2->ptrSig = ptrFin;
    printf("%d ", ptrRec2->num);
    printf("\n");
    return (ptrIni, ptrFin);
}

struct nodo *conectFilas (struct nodo *ptrIniL, struct nodo *ptrIniV, struct nodo *ptrFinL, struct nodo *ptrFinV, int nmb)
{
    int cic = 1;
    int rec = 1;
    struct nodo *ptrRec1, *ptrRec2;
    for(cic;cic<=4;cic++)
    {
        crearFila (ptrIniV, ptrFinV, nmb);      //Se crea la nueva fila.
        ptrRec1 = ptrIniL;
        ptrRec2 = ptrIniV;
        for(rec;rec<=5;rec++)                   //Se inicia el enlazamiento de las filas.
        {
            printf("marcador");
            ptrRec1->ptrDwn = ptrRec2;          //ERROR INICIA AQUI.-------------------------------------------------------
            printf("marcador");
            ptrRec2->ptrUp = ptrRec1;
            if (rec!=5)
            {
                ptrRec1 = ptrRec1->ptrSig;
                ptrRec2 = ptrRec2->ptrSig;
            }
        }
        ptrIniL = ptrIniV;
        ptrFinL = ptrFinV;
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(cic;cic>=1;cic--)
    {
        ptrIniL = ptrIniL->ptrUp;
        ptrFinL = ptrFinL->ptrUp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Si la función `crearNodo` hace lo que pienso, reservar memoria y crear el objeto para retornar el puntero, esto no te puede funcionar nunca. Estás pasando los punteros por valor a la función y no por referencia. Así que si dentro de la función cambias la dirección de memoria recibida, no se verá reflejada fuera.

De la misma manera que en una función con este prototipo de ejemplo:

```
void funcion( int a)
```

Al entrar en la función se realiza una copia de la variable `a`. Si haces cambios en a dentro de la función, no serán visibles fuera. Si quieres que el parámetro se pase por referencia, cambias el prototipo de la función:

```
void funcion( int* a)
```

Así, si dentro de la función cambias el contenido de la variable `a`, el cambio se verá reflejado al salir de la función. La variable se está pasando por referencia, pero no su dirección de memoria. Si dentro de la función asignas al puntero a otra dirección, al salir seguirá teniendo la misma que antes de entrar.

Si lo que quieres es que sea la función la que reserve memoria para el puntero, osea, cambie su dirección de memoria de entrada, y se vea reflejado fuera, tendrás que pasar la dirección de memoria por referencia y esto se hace con una doble indirección (doble puntero):

```
void funcion( int** a)
```

Así, la llamada la harías así:

```
int* a = NULL;
funcion( &a);
```

Le pasas la dirección de memoria del puntero y entonces el puntero estaría pasándose por referencia y podrás cambiar la dirección a la que apunta.

Comment: Un pequeño apunte: pasar la dirección de memoria de un dato no es "*pasar por referencia*". El lenguaje [tag:c] no dispone de referencias.